# How do I set comments to be flat in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I can only seem to get them to come up as threaded. I'm using forum w/ advanced forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set them in your content type by going to admin/structure/types/manage/forum.

There you can specify how you want show your comments.

[image: screenshot]